# How to delete a file system?

Tags: filesystems, partition

I accidentally formatted my [BIOS boot partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition) as FAT32, but according to Wikipedia:

> the BIOS boot partition is used in BIOS-based systems and accessed *without a filesystem* by holding raw binary code.

Can I delete the file system? Does my question even make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wipefs -a /dev/sdxY` (replace `sdxY` with your partition, e.g. `sda1`, without the `-a` `wipefs` will just print the filesystem signatures on the device, so you can check with just `wipefs /dev/sdxY` to make sure you are wiping the correct partition).

You can also use `dd` to write zeroes to the partition (`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdxY`) but wiping the filesystem signature is enough to make the partition "empty".

Comment: The partition was not "empty" from the beginning. The data that was on the partition needs to be restored, i.e. the parts of GRUB that were stored on the partition before they were partially overwritten by the formatting. GRUB needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: I assumed the question was about preparing storage layout for a new installation so the partition was empty/unused. But yes, if this is an existing system reinstalling the bootloader will be necessary.